Can you clip just the top of a wall mirror if it is glued?
I'm installing two 24x48 mirrors, one above the other. I want for there to be as little space between them on the side they'll meet. Can I just use glue for the bottom section of the top mirror and put mirror clips on the top? Or do I REALLY need to place a clip on the bottom section of the top mirror too?

Is there a reason you don't want to glue the top of the mirror too?

Please be aware that if you choose to use glue, then you're gluing the mirror to the surface of the wall - in other words, to the paint on the wall. This means that you're relying on the paint (however many layers there may be) to not peel off the wall. It doesn't matter how strong the glue is if the paint between it and the wall gives way!

You can use the proper mastic or glue and have no clips. Just need to support the mirror until the glue has dried.
There is a trade off.  Using glue will mean the wall will be damaged when the mirror is removed. Of course there are no clips showing.
If you use clips only, there is the esthetic issue, but only small holes to repair when the mirrors are no longer wanted.
Just be sure if you are using a glue, that you use a product made for the type of mirror you have,  Some glues, like Pl530 is for glass mirrors but not for acrylic.
I had mirrors in my home that were glued in place in 1984. Some were 4' x 8'.  They were still a pain to remove when I purchased the home in 2015.

You can glue them, and if you use the right product and prepare the wall and mirror well, it ought to last a long time.  But it might not.   With a glass mirror that large I wouldn't risk it, but you can.
If you want it to look almost seamless you have options:

Instead of chunky plastic clips, there are chromed metal mirror clips that are only about a mm thick.  Find the most subtle ones you can.  If they create a mm gap between mirrors is it that bad? I mean the seam isn't going to be invisible anyway.
You can reduce that mm to zero by making small diagonal cuts in the corners of the mirrors and using corner clips.
Have holes drilled for screws, and use mirrored screw caps over the screws.

Each one of those options shows slightly, in different ways ... maybe one of them will be ok for you. Or:

Use an industrial process like 3M VHB tape and follow the instructions for industrial application --- that means buy appropriate primer for the mirror and for the wall (which may not be the same primer), a roller, read the instructions, watch the training on youtube, and follow all the steps carefully.   Since no drywall or painted surface can be relied on this way, screw a better surface (read the instructions) to the studs and glue the mirror to that.  This stuff is used to hold car body panels onto cars so if you take all the steps it should be fine for this job.

